# java file readline returns null

Tags: java, null, readline, filereader

I am trying to create a booking system in Java, however every time I run the program the while loop (shown below) skips straight to the end as though the line read was null

```
   //hardcoded file path - needs to be changed when program moved
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\BOO\\Desktop\\SystemsSoftwareBookingsystem\\FilmData.txt";
            String line = null;
            int readInt = 0;
            float readFloat = 0;
            int item_counter = 0;

    try
            {

             BufferedReader bufferedReaderF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));  

 while ((line = bufferedReaderF.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Film tmpFilm = new Film();

                switch (item_counter)
                {
                    case 0:
                {
                    line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();
                    tmpFilm.name = line;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.seatsTotal = readInt;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.seatsAvailable = readInt;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.price = readFloat;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.showingTime = readFloat;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.day = readInt;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 6:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.month = readInt;
                    item_counter++;
                    break;
                }
                case 7:
                {
                    readInt = bufferedReaderF.read();
                    tmpFilm.year = readInt;
                    item_counter = 0;
                    break;
                }
                }

                line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();

                server.filmList.add(tmpFilm);

            }

            bufferedReaderF.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    }
}`
```

any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT added rest of the code in the while loop as requested

EDIT here is the file I am reading from

```
Film 1
10
10
5.00
10.30
Wednesday 23rd
July
2013
```

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't empty?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is related to the problem, but you need to put `break;` statements after every code sequence in your `switch`.  Otherwise, if say `item_counter` is 0, it will execute the code for 0, and then fall through and execute the code for 1, and then for 2, etc.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out - i've fixed that now but it wasn't what was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove-

```
line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();
```

And read in the loop-

```
while ((line = bufferedReaderF.readLine()) != null)
```

Check if the file is empty. Can you also update your question with code inside while?

Based from your edit-

You are ignoring what you are reading in while. Should be something like this-

```
switch (item_counter)
{
    case 0:
    {
        tmpFilm.name = line;
        item_counter++;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {                    
        tmpFilm.seatsTotal = Integer.parseInt(line);
        item_counter++;
        break;
    }
    ...etc...
```

Comment: That bottom line does not compile, it needs to be `while((line = bufferedReaderF.readLine()) != null){ ..... }`.

Comment: @JimGarrison - His variable name is "bufferedReaderF".

Comment: I reverted the edit already; however, this answer does not appear to address the actual problem.  The edit suggested, if not coupled with removing the additional read _at the end of the loop_ will cause alternate input lines to be skipped.

Comment: i have tried making these changes but unfortunately it still won't work for some reason

Comment: @JimGarrison - The answer was given before the edit in question was made...also the edit in question was made because of what I requested in answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
BufferedReader bufferedReaderF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));  
line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();
 while (line != null)
                {
                    Film tmpFilm = new Film();

                    switch (item_counter)
                    {
                        case 0:
                        {
                           // line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();
                            tmpFilm.name = line;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1:
                        {
                            readInt=Integer.parseInt(line);
                            tmpFilm.seatsTotal = readInt;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2:
                        {
                            readInt = Integer.parseInt(line);
                            tmpFilm.seatsAvailable = readInt;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3:
                        {
                            readFloat=Float.parseFloat(line);
                            tmpFilm.price = readFloat;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4:
                        {
                            readFloat=Float.parseFloat(line);
                            tmpFilm.showingTime = readFloat;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 5:
                        {
                            line=line.replaceAll("\\D","");
                            readInt = Integer.parseInt(line);
                            tmpFilm.day = readInt;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 6:
                        {
                            readInt = Integer.parseInt(GregorianCalendar.class.getField(line.toUpperCase()).get(line))+1;
                            tmpFilm.month = readInt;
                            item_counter++;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 7:
                        {
                            readInt = Integer.parseInt(line);
                            tmpFilm.year = readInt;
                            item_counter = 0;                   
                        }
                    }

                    line = bufferedReaderF.readLine();

                    server.filmList.add(tmpFilm);

                }
```